# Demoting or reducing severity of a Pylint message

Tags: pylint, pylintrc

There is this potentially useful but also pesky Pylint message which we would prefer to keep enabled and written to the console (and especially to the CI log), but only if Pylint can be told to return a 0 exit code if it finds nothing more severe (so we do not have to keep suppressing/unsuppressing it whenever adding/removing breakpoints or changing our workflow which requires 0 exit code from Pylint at a very early stage)

```
W1515: Leaving functions creating breakpoints in production code is not recommended (forgotten-debug-statement)
```

I checked the FAQ and the command-line help. There is the opposite switch `--fail-on` but  no obvious way to *reduce* the severity. Also checked the [changelog](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/blob/main/ChangeLog) up to 2.13.0.

---

For now our poor people's workaround is to use `grep` instead of the one simple Pylint warning which we now disabled.

```sh
grep 'set_trace()\|breakpoint()' \
  --dereference-recursive        \
  --include='*.py'               \
  $PYTHON_CODE_DIRECTORY         \
  ||true
```

But the question is how to demote (reduce severity of) any specific Pylint warning.